# Return a value from a list of type synonyms

Tags: haskell, type-synonyms

So I want to return a value from a list of type synonyms.

```
type Skill = (String,Int)
type Stat = (String,Int)
data Player = Player {
                   hitpoints :: Int,
                   experience :: Int,
                   stats :: [Stat],
                   skills :: [Skill],
                   pos :: Point
                   }
```

I want to return the value of the stat `"Toughness"` in

`Player 10 0 [ ("Strength", 5), ("Toughness", 1) ] [ ("Fisticuffs", 1) ] (1,1)`

So far I have

```
instance Combatant Player where
defense (Player _ _ ([(s,a)]) _ _) = (List.find (s=="Toughness") ([(s,a)]))
```

but it returns the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int'
            with actual type `Maybe (GHC.Base.String, Int)'
In the expression: (find (s == "Toughness") ([(s, a)]))
In an equation for `defense':
    defense (Player _ _ ([(s, a)]) _ _)
      = (find (s == "Toughness") ([(s, a)]))


Couldn't match expected type `(GHC.Base.String, Int)
                              -> ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Types.Bool'
            with actual type `ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Types.Bool'
In the first argument of `find', namely `(s == "Toughness")'
In the expression: (find (s == "Toughness") ([(s, a)]))
In an equation for `defense':
    defense (Player _ _ ([(s, a)]) _ _)
      = (find (s == "Toughness") ([(s, a)]))
```

I'm still new to Haskell and I don't know what I should do. I've looked at different sources and closes thing I've seen to this is Association lists ?

Answer (score 2):

Type-synonyms has nothing to do with your problem. One great thing about functional programming is that it allows you to abstract more and more ways to combine results. So all common problems are already solved, you only need to find names of solutions. Take a look at [`Data.List`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.17/base-4.8.1.0/Data-List.html), it has [`lookup`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.17/base-4.8.1.0/Data-List.html#v:lookup) function:

```
λ> lookup "Toughness" [("Strength", 5), ("Toughness", 1)]
Just 1
```

You see that you currently have no guarantees on type level that you'll find something labelled `"Toughness"` at all. Thus we get `Maybe Int`. Now you should ask yourself a question, can player exist without `"Toughness"` parameter at all? Probably not. So a better approach would be just:

```
data Player = Player
  { hitpoints       :: Int
  , experience      :: Int
  , statStrength    :: Int
  , statToughness   :: Int
  , skillFisticuffs :: Maybe Int
  , pos             :: Point }
```

This is much better, you're now *guaranteed* by the language that any player will have some strength, etc. I don't know about skills in your game, you can make them optional with `Maybe` wrapper or keep them in a map (list of tuples) with the same effect (see `lookup`, it also returns `Maybe Int`).